# Wrap boxes in display: flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am using `display: flex;` to have all blocks of same height. These blocks are dynamically generated and their can be **n** numbers of blocks.

[Here is my code.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WbRROW)

What I want is blocks which are moving out of the red box. They should get in the second row.

Is this possible using `display: flex` ? **or** Is there any other way to achieve this output.

Comment: Its working on my side. Its this link. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WbRROW

Comment: Like this ? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYJJQa

Comment: I'm just saying, I've tried this on two computers and my tablet and it has the same result as yours @Danko. It isn't my firewall so... :-P

Comment: @Danko you are right, however I wanted it to be of same width. [Like this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jEyyxN). Still your solution help me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add this property:

```
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

Comment: I would also recommend this article: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ by CSS Tricks. It covers this topic pretty well.